# script to remember dir and always cd to it instead of the root dir

Tags: bash, shell-script, cd-command

How can write a script to change to a given directory but also remember it so that when you do cd it always changes to that directory ?

```
#!/bin/bash
setdir() {
    cd $1
    # remember the directory we are changing to here so whenever we do cd we go back to this set dir
}

setdir "$1"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
setdir() {
    cd "$1"
    export SETDIR_DEFAULT="$1"
}

my_cd() {
    cd "${1-${SETDIR_DEFAULT-$HOME}}"
}
```

Note that these are functions, not a separate script. You can't do that from a separate script, since it would not be able to affect the parent shell that calls it.

If you *really* want to override `cd` (please, don't do that), replace `cd` with `builtin cd`.

Answer (score 1):

I know it might be a bit late for the answer, but you might like the idea of `CDPATH` vaiable. It allows `cd` to refer to content of directories in this variable from anywhere. Here's an example:

```
$ mkdir -p test/{1,2,3}
$ cd test/
$ mkdir 1/{a,b,c}
$ export CDPATH=/tmp/test/1
$ ls
1  2  3
$ cd a
$ pwd
/tmp/test/1/a
$ cd ~
$ cd b
$ pwd
/tmp/test/1/b
```

More details from `man`:

```
   CDPATH    A <colon>-separated list of pathnames 
             that refer to directories. The cd utility 
             shall use this list in its attempt to  change  
             the directory,  as described in the DESCRIPTION. 
             An empty string in place of a directory 
             pathname represents the current directory. If
             CDPATH is not set, it shall be treated as if 
             it were an empty string.
```